# Does not add marker to map dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, google-maps-api-3

The map's click event triggers when a radio button is clicked,the `confirm` and the `prompt` messages are displayed on the screen but the marker does not get added to the map.I have chosen to use the following event because it automatically unregisters the event after the callback executes:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(addTo,'click',function(event){
    var sure=confirm('Add a marker here?');
    var name;
    var marker;
    if(sure)
    {
        name=prompt('Enter a name:');
        if(name===null)
            name='Marker';
        marker=createMapMarker(event.latLng,name);
        marker=addMarkerToCurrentMap(addTo);

    }   
});
```

## EDIT:

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/4g5Q2/).It does not contain my API key,to get the map to load add API key where it says KEY in loadScript.

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle. Your question is not clear but if I refer to the title of your post: did you try removeListener or clearListeners? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapsEventListener

Comment: @MrUpsidown I have updated the question to be much more specific to the problem I am currently facing.

Comment: Your fiddle does not work. We don't care about the API key. Add it as an external resource on jsfiddle. And your code calls functions that do not exist.